# KineticJS drawImage function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using the KineticJS library on my website, to add some functionality to an HTML5 canvas game I'm making.

I am drawing a number of images to the canvas using the library, but it's not quite drawing the images as I had hoped.

The images I'm drawing are all stored in an array, and are currently all being drawn to the canvas. However, they are all being drawn on top of each other, in the same location. This is fine in theory, since the user can drag and drop the images around the canvas, so they would be able to view them all by doing that. However, it's not particularly user friendly, since I am drawing roughly 30 images to the canvas, so for the user to have to move them all individually in order to be able to see them all at the same time is not particularly helpful.

I am using a version of the KineticJS library that I have saved locally, since there are one or two changes I wanted to make to the functionality it provided.

The function in the library that I'm using to draw the images looks like this:

```
drawImage: function() {
        var context = arguments[0];
        context.save();
        var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        if(a.length === 6 || a.length === 10) {
            if(a.length === 6) {
                context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
            }
            else {
                context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]);
            }
        }

        context.restore();


    }
```

and this function draws all of the images on top of each other, all in the same location (top left hand corner of the canvas).

I want to edit this function, to create a 'grid' of locations at which the images in the array will be drawn. It doesn't matter if more than one image is drawn to the same grid cell, but at least there would images in more than one location.

I had tried doing this using a function I wrote- my function worked when used on its own, however when I tried to use it alongside the library, it then didn't work. So, I was wondering if I could potentially edit the drawImage function in the library, to include the code I wrote to create the 'grid' layout to draw the images to.

The function I wrote for drawing the images in a grid layout looks like this:

```
function drawImage(imageObj) {
    /* Create variables to select the array position randomly*/
    var randomXPosition = function getRandomXPosition(minX, maxX){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxX - minX +1)) +minX;
    }
    var randomYPosition = function getRandomYPosition(minY, maxY){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxY - minY +1)) +minY;
    }

    /* Create arrays of X & Y coordinates, and select the array elements randomly for use as
        coordinates at which to draw the images*/
    var xPos = new Array();
    xPos[0] = 10;
    xPos[1] = 70;
    xPos[2] = 130;
    xPos[3] = 190;
    xPos[4] = 250;
    xPos[5] = 310;
    xPos[6] = 370;
    xPos[7] = 430;
    xPos[8] = 490;
    xPos[9] = 550;
    xPos[10] = 610;
    xPos[11] = 670;
    xPos[12] = 730;
    xPos[13] = 790;
    xPos[14] = 850;
    xPos[15] = 910;

    var yPos = new Array();
    yPos[0] = 40;
    yPos[1] = 100;
    yPos[2] = 160;
    yPos[3] = 220;
    yPos[4] = 280;
    yPos[5] = 340;
    yPos[6] = 400;
    yPos[7] = 460;

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,

      /* Now select a random X & Y position from the arrays to draw the images to */
      x: xPos[randomXPosition()],
      y: yPos[randomYPosition()],
      draggable: true

      /* puts the images in random locations on the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 20*Math.floor(Math.random()*20),
      y: stage.getHeight() / 15*Math.floor(Math.random()*8+2),
      draggable: true */
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}
```

This function creates the grid layout of canvas coordinates using the X and Y positions, and then assigns a random element from the X and Y coordinate arrays to each image's X and Y values when they are drawn to the canvas- ensuring that each image is drawn on the canvas at a random location within the list of possible locations that I have determined.

What I want to know is how I can add the functionality that the function I've written provides, to the `drawImage` function in the library?

I tried copying and pasting my code into the function in the library, so for example:

```
drawImage: function() {
        var context = arguments[0];
        context.save();
        var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        if(a.length === 6 || a.length === 10) {
            if(a.length === 6) {
                context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
            }
            else {
                context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]);
            }
        }

        /* Create variables to select the array position randomly*/
    var randomXPosition = function getRandomXPosition(minX, maxX){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxX - minX +1)) +minX;
    }
    var randomYPosition = function getRandomYPosition(minY, maxY){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxY - minY +1)) +minY;
    }

    /* Create arrays of X & Y coordinates, and select the array elements randomly for use as
        coordinates at which to draw the images*/
    var xPos = new Array();
    xPos[0] = 10;
    xPos[1] = 70;
    xPos[2] = 130;
    xPos[3] = 190;
    xPos[4] = 250;
    xPos[5] = 310;
    xPos[6] = 370;
    xPos[7] = 430;
    xPos[8] = 490;
    xPos[9] = 550;
    xPos[10] = 610;
    xPos[11] = 670;
    xPos[12] = 730;
    xPos[13] = 790;
    xPos[14] = 850;
    xPos[15] = 910;

    var yPos = new Array();
    yPos[0] = 40;
    yPos[1] = 100;
    yPos[2] = 160;
    yPos[3] = 220;
    yPos[4] = 280;
    yPos[5] = 340;
    yPos[6] = 400;
    yPos[7] = 460;

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,

      /* Now select a random X & Y position from the arrays to draw the images to */
      x: xPos[randomXPosition()],
      y: yPos[randomYPosition()],
      draggable: true

      /* puts the images in random locations on the canvas
      x: stage.getWidth() / 20*Math.floor(Math.random()*20),
      y: stage.getHeight() / 15*Math.floor(Math.random()*8+2),
      draggable: true */
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);

        context.restore();


    }
```

But when viewing the page in the browser after doing this, the canvas no longer appears on the page, and I'm given the console error: "ReferenceError: imageObj is not defined" on the line `image: imageObj,`.

I can't figure out why this is, or how to fix it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit 30/01/2013 @ 16:10**

I've tried editing the code as suggested, and the drawImage function now looks like this:

```
drawImage: function() {
        var context = arguments[0];
        context.save();
        var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        /*Create the arrays to hold the grid coordinates I want to use */
        /* Create variables to select the array position randomly*/
        var randomXPosition = function getRandomXPosition(minX, maxX){
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxX - minX +1)) +minX;
        }
        var randomYPosition = function getRandomYPosition(minY, maxY){
            return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxY - minY +1)) +minY;
        }

        /* Create arrays of X & Y coordinates, and select the array elements randomly for use as
            coordinates at which to draw the images*/
        var xPos = new Array();
        xPos[0] = 10;
        xPos[1] = 70;
        xPos[2] = 130;
        xPos[3] = 190;
        xPos[4] = 250;
        xPos[5] = 310;
        xPos[6] = 370;
        xPos[7] = 430;
        xPos[8] = 490;
        xPos[9] = 550;
        xPos[10] = 610;
        xPos[11] = 670;
        xPos[12] = 730;
        xPos[13] = 790;
        xPos[14] = 850;
        xPos[15] = 910;

        var yPos = new Array();
        yPos[0] = 40;
        yPos[1] = 100;
        yPos[2] = 160;
        yPos[3] = 220;
        yPos[4] = 280;
        yPos[5] = 340;
        yPos[6] = 400;
        yPos[7] = 460;

        var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: a[1],
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            x: xPos[randomXPosition()],
            y: yPos[randomYPosition()],
            draggable: true
        });
        canvasImage.on('mouseover', function(){/*Define any handlers I want*/});
        imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
    }
```

However, although the canvas is now displayed, the images are not- there is a square 'outline' where the images were previously appearing (when they were all being drawn to the one location), so I assume that's the images, but they're not displaying as images- just a square, and they're still all in the same location.

When I try to drag and drop the square around the canvas (assuming that it is an image), everything else that has been drawn to the canvas moves with the image, and it has all become very slow and unresponsive.

For example, here's a screenshot of my page:

[image]

Is there something I've done wrong with how I edited the code?

Comment: any chance you could put a jsfiddle together? I can better help you that way.

Comment: I could put a jsfiddle together- but bearing in mind the kineticjs library I'm using is almost 7,000 lines long, it might be a bit too big? But I could put one up just with the bits of the library that are relevant to my question if you like?

Comment: Well, can you paste the library somewhere and just link the fiddle to it? if not, paste the whole library. I'll just scroll to the bottom to find the drawing code.

Comment: also, screenshot is not very visible.

Comment: Hi there, I've pasted my local copy of the kinetic library here: http://jsfiddle.net/sPxsr/  The drawImage function starts on line 4233

Comment: The errors I'm currently getting say `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available` and they're complaining about the line `context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);` inside the 'if' statement at the start of the function. This is not code that I wrote- it is what was already in library before I started editing it. I'm not really sure what that if statement does, but if I comment it out, the images from my array are not displayed- there's just a square outline where they would be, and if I click on it, it randomly jumps around the canvas, and the page then crashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by the fact that imageObj, the javascript object you are referencing, is not defined anywhere in your code (that you have shown).

Notes:

```
var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
  image: imageObj,   // <--- imageObj needs to be created somewhere, it is expecting something like:  var imageObj = new Image();
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  x: xPos[randomXPosition()],
  y: yPos[randomYPosition()],
  draggable: true

});
```

Now, for the fix:
You need to reference wherever your images are stored; an array?

```
var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
  image: a[0],   
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  x: xPos[randomXPosition()],
  y: yPos[randomYPosition()],
  draggable: true

});
```

**New Stuff:** 
This is your function:

```
  drawImage: function() {
    var context = arguments[0];
    context.save();
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    if(a.length === 6 || a.length === 10) {
        if(a.length === 6) {
            context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);  //a[1] contains the image object reference
        }
        else {
            context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9]);
        }
    }

    context.restore();
  }
```

try:

```
  drawImage: function() {
    var context = arguments[0];
    context.save();
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var randomSpot = randomGridPosition();
    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: a[1],   
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        x: randomSpot.x,
        y: randomSpot.y,
        draggable: true
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function(){/*define any handlers you want*/};
    layer.add(canvasImage); //or whatever your layer is called
  }
```

Random Grid Position:

```
  function randomGridPosition(){  //10x10 grid
      var width= .9*stage.getWidth()/10;
      var height= .9*stage.getHeight()/10;
      var randomX = Math.floor(10*Math.random()*width); //select random x position dependent on width
      var randomY = Math.floor(10*Math.random()*height); //select random y position dependent on height
      return {x: randomX, y: randomY};
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From what I can see, the only other place that I've used the variable `imageObj` in the function I've copied the code from was in the function definition, i.e. the line: `function drawImage(imageObj) {.... ` So should I change the function definition in the library from `drawImage: function() {...` to `drawImage: function(imageObj) {... ` ?

Comment: I gave that a try, but although the canvas was now displayed, with everything on it, the images are all still drawn on top of each other. Also, when I click on an image to drag it to another location, everything except that image disappears from the canvas and I'm given the console error: "TypeError: value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement" on the line `context.drawImage(a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);`

Comment: what is stored in the a[] array?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure- it was code that was already in the drawImage function in the library. If it helps, the a[] array is declared just above where it's passed into the drawImage function. It's declared using the line: `var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` I've not seen this kind of code before... so I haven't really got a clue what it's doing. The 'arguments' variable that's being passed into the parenthesis here is first used in the file in this segment of code: `for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            arr.push(arguments[i]);
        }`

Comment: But I can't see anywhere that 'arguments' is defined... I assume it's an array?

Comment: Then it does store some images. Take a look: context.drawImage(img,x,y,width,height); is the definition if length is 6. context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height); is the definition of a clipped image.

Comment: I'm going to change my answer.. by a lot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updated answer. I've tried what you suggested, and I'm now getting a console error that says that xPos is not defined- I assume this is because I no longer have the xPos and yPos arrays where I had stored the 'grid locations' I wanted to use? Theoretically, if I add these back in, it should then work I think? Presumably I would put the arrays right at the start of the function along with the other variables? i.e. just underneath `var context = arguments[0];
            context.save();
            var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: xpos and ypos need to be defined before canvasImage. Or why not just create a function that generates a random position on the screen?

Comment: see the new position calculation function and new canvasImage definition

Comment: Hi there, I've copied the two functions you provided into my kineticJS file, replacing the drawImage function that was previously there, however, when I now view the page in the browser, the canvas does not display, and I get two console errors that say: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and "ReferenceError: Kinetic is not defined". Both of these errors reference line 39 in my index.html page, which is the line `var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({`  any idea why this is?

Comment: I've checked, and the corresponding ) for the ( on that line is definitely there, but I don't know why Kinetic would not be defined... I've included the KineticJS file with the line `<script src="kinetic.js"></script>`

Comment: then simply put, you are missing a closing brace/parentheses somewhere else.

Comment: I've had a thorough look through the whole file, and as far as I can tell, every opening brace/ parentheses has a corresponding closing brace/ parentheses. I'm almost 100% certain that there are not any that have been opened and not closed, and no random closing ones either. Is there any other reason why I might get this error? The two errors I'm currently getting say `missing } after property list` and `Kinetic is not defined`. The first one is complaining about a line in the kinetic.js file, and the second about a line in the index.html file.